# Segmentation Fault error while running pymatlab in Python

Tags: python, matlab, segmentation-fault

I am using Ubuntu 17.10

Python version: 2.7.14 Anaconda

I have Matlab R2017b installed. I also installed pymatlab-0.2.3

When I run following commands in python, I get "**Segmentation fault (core dumped)**" and ipython closes.

`import pymatlab
session = pymatlab.session_factory(options = 'nodesktop -nodisplay')`

Also, when I debugged it using **gdb**, it gives following stack trace:

`Starting program: /home/jsingla/anaconda2/bin/python test.py
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff17f8029 in engOutputBuffer () from /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/glnxa64/libeng.so`

Comment: Did you make sure of requirements here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pymatlab?  
Especially cshell and path variable. 

Also, check numpy version

Comment: I have downgraded my numpy version to 1.3.0 and I am using python 2.7
You think I also need to go to Matlab2013a?? Because I used to have this working on Ubuntu 14.04 with latest numpy and Matlab, but now I have shifted to Ubuntu 17.10 and it stopped working.

Comment: Oh it might have something to do with ubuntu version. Generally, if you are not a Linux enthusiast and don't want to spend time debugging random issues you should use LTS version (16.04 in this case)

Comment: btw is your matlab launching without python? Try running `matlab nodesktop -nodisplay` on terminal

Comment: it is launching without python